# Excel-VBA REST WCF works on 1st call, but subsequent calls return cached (non-current) data

Tags: wcf, rest, excel, vba

I have a basic WCF client service in the form below.  The first time it is called, it returns the correct data from the remote server.  However the data changes frequently.  On subsequent calls, it returns the same data that it did on the first call.  So, Excel appears to return cached data.
If I run the same WCF procedure from Fiddler or a browser, it seems to always return current/refreshed data (so I think the issue is in Excel, not the server).
How can I force Excel VBA to "refresh" the call instead of getting the data from cache?
Note: this will be distributed to a variety of end users, so I cannot make client config changes.

```
Public Function CallWCF() As String
   Dim HttpReq As Object
   Set HttpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
   HttpReq.Open "GET", "http://ws.mydomain.com/Rest.svc/getmydata"
   Call HttpReq.Send
   Do While HttpReq.readyState <> 4
     DoEvents
   Loop
   Dim resp As String
   resp = HttpReq.ResponseText
   CallWCF = resp
   Set HttpReq = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055475/vbscript-disable-caching-of-response-from-server-to-http-get-url-request

Comment: You can usually force a re-fetch of data which is somehow otherwise being cached by appending a "dummy" querystring parameter to your URL. Eg. `http://ws.mydomain.com/Rest.svc/getmydata?xxx=someLongRandomNumber`

Comment: Another possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11526810/190829

Comment: From [link]stackoverflow.com/q/11526810/190829, it appears that adding:    `HttpReq.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"` solved the issue on my PC (don't know if it will work on all PCs with different browsers).  The other 2:  `   'HttpReq.setRequestHeader "Cache-Control", "no-cache"
'HttpReq.setRequestHeader "Pragma", "no-cache"`  did not seem to help.

Comment: I also tried appending the URL with a dummy parameter that changes each request (such as the time or random number) and that also works.  However I think it will require changing the server code for all of my operations.

Comment: If you solved your problem, you should post the solution as an answer (instead of a comment) and mark it as solved, even if you solved it yourself. That way, others can see that your issue was resolved (and how to resolve it themselves).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [stackoverflow.com/q/11526810/190829](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11526810/190829), it appears that adding:
 `httpReq.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"`
solved the issue on my PC (don't know if it will work on all PCs with different browsers). The other 2: 
    `HttpReq.setRequestHeader "Cache-Control", "no-cache"` and 
    `HttpReq.setRequestHeader "Pragma", "no-cache"` 
did not seem to help.

I also tried appending the URL with a dummy parameter that changes each request (such as the time or random number) and that also works. However I think it will require changing the server code for all of my operations.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with calling a resource with GET and having a cached response. the way i solved it is calling a "PUT" (or anything else that's not supported) and then call your useful "GET" - that way it'll force a new connection, in term severing the persistence.