# Populate excel column with data from a URL

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a situation in which I need to populate a specific column from an URL ( Basically a get request to that URL will give a list of numbers ).

I am new with the macros but I want to make a system in which I will click a button and then that will read the data and populate the column.

**Edit:**

I have a URL, let's say `161.202.176.187/importData.txt` and it has the following data.

```
12345
67890
12345
09876
87653
14214
14566
46131
12456
35098
```

Now in my excel, I have a button like this :

[image]

and I need to populate the column `A1` with the data.

Comment: I think you have to provide more details ...

Comment: Please consult this for a minimal example of what you already did: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - if you only say what you want, maybe a freelance site would be a better place

Comment: Added the details.

Comment: Minimal yes but complete and Verifiable not sure. Do you have an actual URL you have been working with? We have no idea where in the return information the column of information you are after is stored. You can look through the many many many questions on SO re extracting information from webscraping and see which closes matches your requirement. Maybe identify the classname or id associated with what you are after and looping over a collection.

Comment: @QHarr, http://161.202.184.168/excelimport.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such as this to extract?

Windows machines:

add the reference in to microsoft xml and to html object library VBE > tools > references

Also, XMLHTTP60 will need to be adjusted (the 60 bit) to the appropriate version for your Excel.

```
' "http://161.202.184.168/excelimport.txt"

Sub Getinfo3()

    Dim http As New XMLHTTP60
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument

    With http
        .Open "GET", "http://161.202.184.168/excelimport.txt", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

   Dim returnArray() As String
   returnArray = Split(html.body.innerText, " ")

   Dim currentItem As Long

   For currentItem = LBound(returnArray) To UBound(returnArray)
       ActiveSheet.Cells(currentItem + 1, 1) = returnArray(currentItem)
   Next currentItem

End Sub
```

And internet explorer version (requires reference to Microsoft Internet Controls and html object library

```
Public Sub scrapeaIE()

    Dim appIE As Object
    Dim ihtml As Object

    Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

    With appIE

        .Visible = True
        .navigate "http://161.202.184.168/excelimport.txt"

        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set ihtml = .document

    End With

    Dim returnArray() As String
    returnArray = Split(ihtml.body.innerText, vbNewLine)

    Dim currentItem As Long

    For currentItem = LBound(returnArray) To UBound(returnArray)
        ActiveSheet.Cells(currentItem + 1, 1) = returnArray(currentItem)
    Next currentItem

    appIE.Quit

    Set appIE = Nothing

End Sub
```

References included to use both (Excel 2016)

[image: References]

1. Internet Controls
2. XML Library (version for your excel)
3. HTML Object library (version for your excel)

Edit:

For Mac:

You may be able to do something with [AppleScript and MacScript](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/107972-accessing-web-page-via-safari-on-mac-using-vba)

### Edit:

The OP running the code starting getting cache data returning after the first run with each new URL. In the same way as [Excel-VBA REST WCF works on 1st call, but subsequent calls return cached (non-current) data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620747/excel-vba-rest-wcf-works-on-1st-call-but-subsequent-calls-return-cached-non-cu)

The resolution was to add:

```
.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
```

Before

```
.send
```

Comment: I tried running it but it gives `Error 'Compile Error: User-defined type not defined' Attempting to Compile Code` as error. I followed this link https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/858611/error-compile-error-user-defined-type-not-defined-attempting-to-compil  , but it just won't compile.

Comment: You need to add the reference in to microsoft xml  and to html object library VBE > tools > references >

Comment: And XMLHTTP60 will be adjusted to the appropriate version number

Comment: Am using office 2016 for mac. I don’t have these many options when I go to reference. Am trying to figure out if I am able to download it somehow.

Comment: I can't test currently but is this a starting point? https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/107972-accessing-web-page-via-safari-on-mac-using-vba

Comment: I ran it on windows and it worked. Will now try to run it on mac and try that out. Where can I set the column address? For example if I want it to start at C10 and fill the column after that?

Comment: I am writing out data with  ActiveSheet.Cells(currentItem + 1, 1)   and the last 1 specified the column. So ,2 would be B and ,3 would be C etc e.g.  ActiveSheet.Cells(currentItem + 1, 3  is column C.

Comment: One more question, after I make changes to the text file, it still shows the last data i.e the data is not getting refreshed.

Comment: If you re-run it should pick up whatever is at that url.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167364/discussion-between-driftking9987-and-qharr).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for PowerQuery, depending on your version of Excel it is either built in or is available as an add-in from Microsoft. So for Excel 2016 you just click the Data tab, then New Query > From Other Sources > From Web and then follow the dialog boxes and job done.

You can find out more from [here](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/connect-to-a-web-page-power-query-b2725d67-c9e8-43e6-a590-c0a175bd64d8)