# Copy and Paste from a URL using VBA

Tags: javascript, excel, vba

I have a button that calls a sub DBA()

I would like this sub to visit a particular URL (for example: https://index.db.com) and copy all of the content and paste it into Application.Worksheets("DBA").

More specifically, I would ideally like to copy and paste the contents from a div that has an id="constituentstable" in the URL's HTML

Grateful for any guidance, thank you,

Comment: The following post may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27066963/scraping-data-from-website-using-vba

Comment: @DavidTansey Thanks checking it out now

Answer (score 0):

A very basic approach would be to use SendKeys. I'm not experienced in opening websites with Excel, but once you have it open, just use

```
Application.SendKeys "^A", True
Application.SendKeys "^C", True
```

and that will select everything in the website and copy it's contents. But I think it would be helpful to look at the link on the comment of your post.