# Excel real time link of excel cells with real time table on website

Tags: excel, web

I would like to have a real time link in excel with a real time table on a website

http://www.truefx.com/

How am I able to do this?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to actively poll the webpage for changes using VBA, I don't think there is a way around this.

This answers how you can periodically call a piece of VBA code: [VBA Macro On Timer style to run code every set number of seconds, i.e. 120 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319683)

And this answers how you can parse information from a webpage using VBA: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27069914/6216216