# Scraping a flight information website

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to this website and also new to coding world. I was given a task of scraping a website for flight-price information. While searching the web, I found stackoverflow and ran the winning code from this link 
[Website data table scraper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41848354/website-data-table-scraper/43012764#43012764)
This is coded for investing.com webpage. When I change the url for my link, it doesn't give me any result. My url is below. It's a bit long because there are few inputs in the string:

https://www.expedia.com/Flights-Search?flight-type=on&starDate=03%2F25%2F2017&endDate=03%2F26%2F2017&_xpid=11905%7C1&mode=search&trip=roundtrip&leg1=from%3ANew+York%2C+NY+%28NYC-All+Airports%29%2Cto%3ASan+Francisco%2C+CA+%28QSF-All+Airports%29%2Cdeparture%3A03%2F25%2F2017TANYT&leg2=from%3ASan+Francisco%2C+CA+%28QSF-All+Airports%29%2Cto%3ANew+York%2C+NY+%28NYC-All+Airports%29%2Cdeparture%3A03%2F26%2F2017TANYT&passengers=children%3A0%2Cadults%3A1%2Cseniors%3A0%2Cinfantinlap%3AY

Like the goal of the above code was to get everything on the page onto an Excel sheet (so, one can use the data however way they want), I want the same thing for the flight website. Can someone please help me with this. I probably think it's too much to ask, but I am in dire need and new to coding. Hope someone can help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I scrape pages with dynamically generated URLs using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23302676/how-do-i-scrape-pages-with-dynamically-generated-urls-using-python)

Comment: Go through the URL : [Scraping a flight information website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23302676/how-do-i-scrape-pages-with-dynamically-generated-urls-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the string is too long for Excel to deal with.  I'm guessing the limit is 255 characters for a URL.  You can try Python or R.  Although, I'm guessing that URL will present a perpetual problem wherever you go with it.