# extract data from website using VBA get nothing

Tags: vba, web, extract, innerhtml

I use below code to read and extract data from websites. But in specific URL (http://www.iamf.ir) there is a problem!

```
    Dim HTML_Content As HTMLDocument
    Dim dados As Object

    'Create HTMLFile Object
    Set HTML_Content = New HTMLDocument

    'Get the WebPage Content to HTMLFile Object
    With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
        .Open "GET", "http://www.iamf.ir", False
        .send
        HTML_Content.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        Debug.Print .responseText                ' it's OK
        Debug.Print HTML_Content.body.innerHTML  ' it show nothing! (problem is here)
    End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the answer to your question, though I don't think it really solves your problem.

The XMLHTTP request you do to this website respond with an empty body, as you can notice from the line `Debug.Print .responseText`:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>&#1575;&#1605;&#1740;&#1606; &#1570;&#1588;&#1606;&#1575; &#1575;&#1740;&#1585;&#1575;&#1606;&#1740;&#1575;&#1606;</TITLE>
        <META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="">
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=http://www.iafi.ir">
        <META NAME="Description" CONTENT="">
    </HEAD> 
    <BODY> <-- body is empty
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

This is why, when you print the `.body.innerHTML` of your `HTML_document`, you get an empty string.

Some websites are built in a way that only the full stack execution (i.e. also JavaScript execution, which doesn't happen when you perform an XMLHTTP request) is able to render correctly what you see in your browser.
In your specific case, you might need to get the information performing a slower but always working scraping based on an invisible browser. You can check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27066963/scraping-data-from-website-using-vba/27069914#27069914) I wrote some time ago to have an idea.

Comment: Thanks bro. I tried your solution. It's Ok but I faced strange problem. Please download my Excel file(https://ufile.io/xc97w). There are 2 buttons that are almost similar. Button 1 is not OK (why?) and Button 2 is OK. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AliM67 if you have a new question, please open a new thread so that other people can help you (here only I will see this comment). In any case, share your code and don't ask to download anything, I don't think anyone would take that risk. Thanks