# Web Scraping from - https://www.reliancepetroleum.com/locateafuelstation

Tags: excel, vba

Request you to please help me in getting data from - https://www.reliancepetroleum.com/locateafuelstation. Here drop down selections has to be made for all the states. I want to extract dropdown search result for all the states on a daily basis. In total this website has 22 -23 states I want all states information in 1 excel sheet. Request you to please automate this via VBA code or any web scraping method.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you just asking someone to code for you? If you need a couple of examples you can perhaps start [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27066963/scraping-data-from-website-using-vba)

Comment: Hi, I have tried using below mentioned VBA but its not copying the data in to the excel sheet.

Comment: I have tried with below VBA but its not copying the data into excel sheet.

Comment: Part one -   Sub extracttablesdata()
Dim IE As Object, obj As Object
Dim mystate As String
Dim t As Integer, r As Integer, c As Integer
Dim elementcollection As Object

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

mystate = InputBox("Enter State")

With IE

.Visible = True
.navigate ("https://www.reliancepetroleum.com/locateafuelstation")

While IE.ReadyState <> 4
DoEvents
Wend
For Each obj In IE.Document.All.Item("States").Options
If obj.innerText = mystate Then
obj.Selected = True
End If
Next obj
IE.Document.getElementsByName("btnSubmit").Item.Click

Comment: Would you like to expand your question including code you've tried, problems, and errors occurred in a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: part 2 -  Do While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:K1000").ClearContents


Set elemCollection = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")

For t = 0 To (elemCollection.Length - 1)
    For r = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows.Length - 1)
        For c = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells.Length)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(r + 1, c + 1) = elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText
    Next c
    Next r
Next t

End With
Set IE = Nothing
End Sub

Comment: Do you get an error? Did you try to debug the code (F8)? Did you read the HTML on the website to know which Elements to pick up? ... I suggest as well you edit you question with the code for people to be more inclined to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this and it works as expected to retrieve data for all States, you simply have to amend the line `HTML.getElementById("storetab").innerText` to get the text from whichever HTML element you wish:

```
Enum READYSTATE
    READYSTATE_UNINITIALIZED = 0
    READYSTATE_LOADING = 1
    READYSTATE_LOADED = 2
    READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE = 3
    READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4
End Enum
Sub Test()
Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
Dim HTML As HTMLDocument
Dim i As Long

strURL = "https://www.reliancepetroleum.com/locateafuelstation"

ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate strURL

Do While (ie.Busy Or ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE)
  DoEvents
Loop

Set HTML = ie.document

Set ctY = HTML.getElementById("idState")
NumberOfoptions = ctY.Options.Length
    For i = 1 To NumberOfoptions
        Set ctY = HTML.getElementById("idState")

        Do While (ie.Busy Or ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE)
          DoEvents
        Loop

        ctY.selectedIndex = i

        HTML.getElementById("idBtnSubmit").Click

        Do While (ie.Busy Or ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE)
          DoEvents
        Loop

        Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value = HTML.getElementById("storetab").innerText

        'ie.GoBack
        ie.navigate strURL

        Do While (ie.Busy Or ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE)
          DoEvents
        Loop

    Next i

End Sub
```