# XMLHTTP Caching: Xml is bringing the same data after the first request Excel VBA

Tags: xml, vba, excel, caching

I'm reading an XML feed using `XMLHTTP`. I noticed that it reads fine the first time when I open the Excel file but, when the XML changes and I run the macro again, it brings in the same previous data. I did some research about how to stop caching. I read that adding a random number as an extra parameter will fix it but didn't work for me.

Any ideas?

```vb
Sub MLB_PinnyParser()

Dim Req As New XMLHTTP
Dim Resp As New DOMDocument
Req.Open "GET", "http://xml.pinnaclesports.com/pinnaclefeed.aspx?sporttype=Baseball&sportsubtype=MLB", False
Req.send
Resp.LoadXML Req.responseText

 For Each Event In Resp.getElementsByTagName("event")

'More code here

 Next Event

Set Req = Nothing
Set Resp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 7):

You can often overcome this by modifying your URL with each request. Just add a random number as a querystring param. For example:

```vb
' Seed the RNG somewhere at the start of your app...
Randomize

...

Sub MLB_PinnyParser()

    ' Generate a random, six-digit number...
    Dim intRand As Long
    intRand = Int((900000) * Rnd) + 100000

    ' Add the number as a param to the request...
    Dim strUrl As String
    strUrl = "http://xml.pinnaclesports.com/pinnaclefeed.aspx?sporttype=Baseball&sportsubtype=MLB" & "&blah=" & intRand

    Dim Req As New XMLHTTP
    Req.Open "GET", strUrl, False
    ...

End Sub
```

Since it sounds like you've tried this already, try adding a couple caching-related headers to your request to see if that makes a difference:

```
Req.SetRequestHeader "Cache-Co­ntrol", "no-cache,max-age=0"
Req.SetRequestHeader "pragma", "no-cache"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'have tried adding these headers and didn't work.. i read that this class was intended to do caching..  How about  using  a different object than XMLHTTP. Do you know any other  like WinHTTPRequest  are you familiar with it ?

Comment: You could try. But take a look at the answer from @barrowc. Sounds like your issue may not be cache-related after all.

Comment: This answer is fine but didn't want to rely on chance (the caching headers don't seem to work either). See @nordscan's answer, it seems more straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

Like this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44857533/6493026)

change "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" to "Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP"

for me works.

Comment: What is the difference ?

Comment: This is the proper solution I believe. Not sure what the difference between them is but the server version seems to ignore caches.

Answer (score 2):

Needed to find a solution that worked for SharePoint lists, and winHTTP is not an option, and the request headers options were not working.

What did work was the following piece of code run before making the MSXML2.XMLHTTP call:

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function InternetSetOptionStr Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "InternetSetOptionA" (ByVal hInternet As Long, ByVal lOption As Long, ByVal sBuffer As String, ByVal lBufferLength As Long) As Integer
Public Sub Clear_Cache()
    InternetSetOptionStr 0, 42, sBuf, 0
End Sub
```

I found this over on the following link [HERE](https://officetricks.com/excel-vba-clear-cache-ie/).

Comment: This answer worked fine but it seems a little over the top and I have a feeling it might not work for requests to a server (I could only test locally). See @nordscan's answer, it seems more straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an XMLHTTP, Excel or VBA issue. The feed you are trying to access is only updated at specific intervals and adding random numbers to the request won't help in this particular case.

If you consult the preamble to the Pinnacle Sports XML feed [here](http://xml.pinnaclesports.com/pinnacleFeed.aspx?) (it will take a few seconds to generate the page), you will see that the XML file returned by the call you are making is only updated every ten minutes. Correct usage is to download that file on your first call, request an incremental update using the timestamp returned from the first call as a parameter to a second call and then request further updates (at most) every 60 seconds by increasing the timestamp accordingly and passing that as a parameter.

Alternatively, you could look at using [their API](http://www.pinnaclesports.com/en/api/manual) instead of the XML feed

Comment: Thank you for your answer. the link i provided is the same link you have but  I've some parameters to target specifically MLB.  My concern  is that if you access  http://xml.pinnaclesports.com/pinnacleFeed.aspx?  directly without adding the last PinnacleFeedTime at the end  will show the live lines.. I have tested this with Don Best  and there isn't such 10 min delay in that way . If  I do it adding the last time param it will show only the changes that happened during that interval.  Basically i need the whole feed every time I query the feed.

Comment: Basically what i need is to read the xml without passing the time parameter in that way i have the Live Lines. I mention this because I  do have a service running in C# using HttpClient which runs every 3 minutes and grabs the whole xml  and then dispose the HttpClient. But  i don't see any way to dispose the Vba XMLHTTP object.  besides closing and opening back the excel file.!

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3055625/2127508) and its comments could give you another route to try by using WinHTTPRequest instead of XMLHTTP