# Why do I need to close and reopen Excel to retrieve an updated value from a URL with Get?

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

The following macro uses the "GET" method to retrieve my reputation score from Chemistry SE.

```
    Dim html_doc As HTMLDocument 

    Sub Chem_SE_RL()    
    ' Collect the number of reputation points from my summary page
        my_url = "http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/4231/ron?tab=topactivity"
        Set html_doc = New HTMLDocument
        Set xml_obj = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

        xml_obj.Open "GET", my_url, False
        xml_obj.send
        html_doc.body.innerHTML = xml_obj.responseText
        Set xml_obj = Nothing

        RL_rep = html_doc.getElementsByClassName("rep")(0).innertext

  ' Do something with the data
    ' 
    '
   End sub()
```

I run the macro and get a value for RL_rep, let's call the value rep_1. I close the workbook, but leave Excel open.  Later in the day I see on the Chemistry SE web page that my rep points have changed so I open the workbook and run the macro again.  However the macro still evaluates RL_rep to be rep_1.

I close Excel, reopen Excel and then run the macro will RL_rep show my updated reputation score. It seems that Excel is retaining some value and to clear it I need to close Excel.

Why is this and is there a way to clear the values from Excel?

Comment: It's possible that the response is being cached on your PC.  Have you tried clearing your IE cache to see if that makes a difference?  or use (eg) Fiddler to monitor the request and see if you can get something from that.

Comment: @TimWilliams Clearing the IE cache had no effect.  Only closing and reopening Excel allows the updated value to be retrieved.

Comment: I would take a look at the responses here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055475/vbscript-disable-caching-of-response-from-server-to-http-get-url-request  In particular, adding a random querystring parameter to your GET URL can work well in this type of situation, because it forces each request to be considered as unique

Comment: @TimWilliams  Thanks for the link Tim, adding a random number to the url fixed my problem.